# JQuery - Show only first paragraph of each article

Tags: jquery

I have a page that will be used to display news articles.

```
<article>

<h4>News Article One</h4>
<h5>25th December 2012</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at purus at dui iaculis adipiscing. Maecenas viverra arcu nec libero accumsan commodo convallis purus sagittis. Etiam fermentum commodo libero sit amet tincidunt. Fusce eu dolor fermentum risus ornare imperdiet rhoncus eu ipsum. Etiam eleifend tempor lacus. Praesent blandit dui at nulla laoreet vehicula. In rhoncus ornare leo venenatis interdum. Vestibulum hendrerit aliquet lectus. Nam ullamcorper ullamcorper sem, a congue massa accumsan vitae.</p>

<p>Etiam ullamcorper mattis lectus, nec mollis odio condimentum vel. Nunc quam ligula, laoreet eu mollis posuere, ultrices varius diam. Ut sapien quam, mattis consequat adipiscing vel, posuere non lacus. Donec id mauris purus. Nam iaculis aliquam pellentesque. Vestibulum eleifend nulla eget lacus aliquam rutrum. Suspendisse adipiscing vestibulum lorem, mattis hendrerit odio faucibus vel.</p>

</article>

<article>

<h4>News Article Two</h4>
<h5>25th January 2012</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at purus at dui iaculis adipiscing. Maecenas viverra arcu nec libero accumsan commodo convallis purus sagittis. Etiam fermentum commodo libero sit amet tincidunt. Fusce eu dolor fermentum risus ornare imperdiet rhoncus eu ipsum. Etiam eleifend tempor lacus. Praesent blandit dui at nulla laoreet vehicula. In rhoncus ornare leo venenatis interdum. Vestibulum hendrerit aliquet lectus. Nam ullamcorper ullamcorper sem, a congue massa accumsan vitae.</p>

<p>Etiam ullamcorper mattis lectus, nec mollis odio condimentum vel. Nunc quam ligula, laoreet eu mollis posuere, ultrices varius diam. Ut sapien quam, mattis consequat adipiscing vel, posuere non lacus. Donec id mauris purus. Nam iaculis aliquam pellentesque. Vestibulum eleifend nulla eget lacus aliquam rutrum. Suspendisse adipiscing vestibulum lorem, mattis hendrerit odio faucibus vel.</p>

</article>
```

I want only the first paragraph of each article to be displayed and to make the rest of the paragraphs, for that article only, to be visible upon clicking a 'read more' link.

Currently I am using this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('article p').eq(1).hide();
 $('a.more').click(function() {
  $('article p').eq(1).show();
  $(this).hide();
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

However the above only works for the first articles, first paragraph and I would like it to work for all of the articles, first paragraphs.

All time and help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('article').each(function(){ $(this).find('p:not(:first)').hide()});
```

Here is a working jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fdp5L/1/

Here is an example with an 'expand link' to each article : http://jsfiddle.net/fdp5L/5/

html:

```
<article>
    <p>first 1</p>
    <p>second 1</p>
    <p>third 1</p>
    <p>fourth 1</p>
    <div class="more">more...</div>
</article>
<article>
    <p>first 2</p>
    <p>second 2</p>
    <p>third 2</p>
    <p>fourth 2</p>
    <div class="more">more...</div>
</article>
```

javascript:

```
$('article').each(function(){ $(this).find('p:not(:first)').hide()});
$('.more').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide().closest('article').find('p').show();    
})
```

Comment: so, you have changed it to be almost the same as my question .. nice! :)

Comment: sorry, I've changed it before I've ready your comment. First solution was wrong :)

Comment: got it, but this does not answer the question, only hides the 2nd paragraph ... it's half question ;)

Comment: @balexandre Have you seen my jsFiddle example? There are two articles with four paragraphs, and my code hides all the paragraphs except the first from each article .

Comment: yes I did saw, @op uses HTML code, so I normally use it, but he does ask that would like to have a read more link and on click, it will show all hidden `<p>`'s ... that´s why I said, "half-answer" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('article').each(function() {
 $('p:eq(1)', this).hide();
});
```

OR

```
$('p:eq(1)', $('article')).hide();
```

OR

```
$('p:gt(0)', $('article')).hide();
```

OR

```
$('p:not(:first)', $('article')).hide();
```

And to show on `.more` click

```
$('a.more').click(function() {
  $('p:eq(1)', $('article')).show();
  $(this).hide();
  return false;
});
```

If `a.more` is direct child of `article` then you can try:

```
$('a.more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('p:eq(1)', $(this).parent()).show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

or if not then try:

```
 $('a.more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).closest("article").find("p:eq(1)").show();
    item.hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple query:

```
$(function() {


  $("article").each(function() {

    // hide all second paragraphs
    $(this).find("p:not(:first)").hide();
    // add read more links
    $(this).find("p:visible").append("<p><a href='#' class='read-more'>read more</a></p>"); 

  });

  $(".read-more").click(function() {

    // show the hided paragraph
    $(this).closest("article").find("p").fadeIn();
    // hide the read more link
    $(this).hide();

  });

});
```

[live example in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ukudax/4/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works nicely.

However I won't necessarily have just two paragraphs so is there a 'hide all but first paragraph' option in JQuery?

Comment: sure: replace `$(this).find("p").eq(1).hide();` by `$(this).find("p:not(:first)").hide()` just like @gabitzish shows :) - edited the answer and example to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$('p:eq(1)', $('article')).hide();
```

**Complete code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p:eq(1)', $('article')).hide();

    $('a.more').click(function() {
        $('p:eq(1)', $('article')).show();
        $(this).hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dZMSD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guesss you want to show all Para except the first one and show the remaining when clicked on the more button/link. This will do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('article p').hide();
    var articles=$('article');
    $.each(articles,function(){
        $(this).find("p").first().show();
    });

 $('a.more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var item=$(this);
    item.closest("article").find("p").show();
    item.hide();
   return false;
 });
});
```

Assuming you have a a tag with class `more` inside the article element.

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/jtQ5b/22/